# Typedef a structure to pointer with same name in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, typedef

I'm trying to include a (.h) header file which is auto-generated by some compiler in my code. Below is the code snip from auto-generated header file.

```
typedef struct SequenceOfUint8 {        // Line 69
    struct SequenceOfUint8 *next;
    Uint8           value;
    } *SequenceOfUint8;                 // Line 72
```

If I include this header file in C code (gcc compiler), it compiles fine without any error, but if try to include this in CPP code, g++ compiler throws below mentioned error.

```
In file included from ssme/src/../include/xxxxx.h:39:0,
                 from ssme/src/ssme.cpp:11:
ssme/src/../include/yyyyy.h:72:4: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct SequenceOfUint8* SequenceOfUint8’
 } *SequenceOfUint8;
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ssme/src/../include/yyyyy.h:69:16: note: previous declaration as ‘struct SequenceOfUint8’
 typedef struct SequenceOfUint8 {
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Can someone please tell how to use this in C++ code (if possible without changing the auto-generated code).

PS: I included the header file in CPP file using `extern "C" { #include "yyyy.h" }` statement, still no luck.

Comment: Wow, that's horrible code.

Comment: You want that SequenceOfUint8 is a struct and a pointer to struct a the same time? Use a different name for the definition of the pointer, like SequenceOfUint8Ptr at line 72

Comment: Do you *need* to compile that as C++? You won't be able to unless you fix the generated code.

Comment: Such a typedef is only possibe in C but not in C++. But even in C it's a bad solution because 1. hiding a pointer type behind a typedef only adds confusion, 2. Haveing the same name for the pointer type than the struct tag is a poor idea. I'd strongly suggest you change the way that code is autogenerated by dropping the typedef alltogether.

Answer (score 6):

You can't use it as is in C++ code. This is another instance where C and C++ being two *different* languages matters.

The tag namespace in C is separate, in C++ it isn't. It doesn't even exist in C++ to be precise.

Wrapping in `extern "C"` is also not going to make a C++ compiler treat the header as C code. That's not the intended function. The header must be standalone valid C++, which it simply isn't.

You will need to write a C wrapper, that exposes a C++ compatible API.

Comment: BTW, this is horrible C code. Separate namespace for identifiers or not, it's a terrible thing to do with an identifier involving the same structure. Confusion is all the more likely with this.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: use this answer at your own risk. I'm not your mom.

Supposing that:

- You can't change the generated code at all
- There are no other use of `typedef` inside the generated file
- You're not afraid of a bit of pragmatic undefined behaviour

```
// <Your lenghty apologetic comment here>
#define typedef static

#include <generated.h>

#undef typedef
```

This will replace all `typedef`s with `static` variables, which *can* hide types. Note that you'll need to use the elaborated type name `struct SequenceOfUint8` to refer to the types later in the same file.

Comment: I think that's wrong what you write because the C code contains a typedef. So, I understand that the C introduces `struct SequenceOfUint8` to be the struct and the name `SequenceOfUint8` to be typedef which names a pointer to such a struct.

Comment: @Handy999 yes. But then replacing `typedef` with `static` defines `SequenceOfUint8` to be a variable of type `struct SequenceOfUint8 *` instead of a type name that would clash.

Comment: That would for sure break any code that assumes SequenceOfUint8 to be a pointer type.

Comment: @Handy999 it would! That's why it's only a last-resort hack for the specific case where it wouldn't break something else ;)

Answer (score 1):

*Is more a remark than an answer, but not practical to do as a remark*

By pity if you are in C++ just replace it by

```
struct SequenceOfUint8 {        // Line 69
   SequenceOfUint8 *next;
   Uint8           value;
};
```

else use *typedef* as usual in C but not to make a *typedef* for `SequenceOfUint8 *`, to make a *typedef* to hide a pointer is catastrophic for the readability of the code, and in your case it was worst because the name is the same

Comment: The question said it was auto-generated so presumably the original poster does not have the luxury or re-writing that part of the code.

Comment: @Ant auto generated does not means without user inputs/requirements ;-)